# Is there a standard MIB to look up a Linux system's users and services via SNMP?

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I know that you can look up open ports and installed software. But is there a way to draw the connection between them to know which service is listening on a port?

And is there any way to look up a system's users?

I am looking for a way that uses the standard MIB's that are present on Linux systems using Net-SNMP.